# SharePoint 2019 Prerequisite Installer Fails During Cumulative Update Package 7 for App Fabric 1.1 for Windows Server Installation

Tags: installation, sharepoint, windows-server-2016, appfabric, sharepoint-2019

I am trying to install SharePoint Server 2019 on a Windows 2016 server, with SQL Server 2016 built into the same server. There is no internet connection on the server, so I have downloaded all the prerequisite application files and I am manually running the PrerequisiteInstaller.exe offline.
When running the Prerequisite Installer, all other files seem to have installed successfully, but I am getting an error during the installation of "**Cumulative Update Package 7 for App Fabric 1.1 for Windows Server**". The products preparation tool runs, but then give the error ***“There was an error during installation. The tool was unable to install Cumulative Update Package 7 for App Fabric 1.1 for Windows Server (KB3092423)”***.
[View Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fcc3Z.png)

There is not much more information in the log (See image):
[View Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fBxWK.png)

When I try to install the application manually using the “AppFabric-KB3092423-x64-ENU.exe” file, it opens the setup wizard, but fails with the error ***“One of the custom actions failed. The installation cannot continue. See logs for details”***.
[View Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wjzv3.png)

Looking in the logs, I get an error ***“CScript Error: Windows Script Host access is disabled on this machine. Contact your administrator for details”***.

I have tried to enable Windows Script host from the registry editor but did not help.
I am also not getting any errors in the event viewer.

Comment: You could check if it is disabled in Group Policy under User Configuration > Administrative Templates > Windows Components > Windows Script Host. Unlikely, but maybe a restart is needed after making config changes too.
I have also seen a suggestion that you could use PowerShell to install this, maybe try that out if the above doesnt work?: Install-Module -Name AppFabric -RequiredVersion 1.1.0.0 -AllowClobber

Comment: What makes this question a [programming question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)? There's a [SharePoint Stack Exchange](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Thanks @MarkL. However, when I go to the location you mentioned there is no Windows Script Host there, under both Computer Configuration and User Configuration. Another thing is that when I try to change the setting through regedit and reboot the server, the value goes back to disabled

Comment: Could you take a look at this answer on SuperUser and see if it helps keeps the registry value after reboot?
https://superuser.com/questions/1534032/registry-key-values-reverted-to-default-after-reboot-in-windows-2019

Comment: Following the article to keep the registry value after reboot worked, but when I run the installer I still get the same error

Answer (score 0):

I managed to resolve this by adding the enabled key to

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows Script Host\Settings

And setting the value to '1'